Need to trigger 10,000 requests in one go without any RampUp or delay in Jmeter
I have a scenario like this,
Login request
Request-1
Request-2
Request-3
Now I want to perform this scenario with 10,000 Users in this way, First all 10,000 Users reaches Login request then all 10,000 users hits Requests-1, 2 & 3 at a time (means all 10,000 requests triggered at the same time in one go)
can anyone pls share Jmeter configuration for this scenario. Thanks :-)


If you want 10 000 users to execute first Request-1 at the same time then Request-2 at the same time and finally Request-3 at the same time - add a Synchronizing Timer at the same level as these "Requests" and set "Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by" to 10000
In case you need to run Request-1, Request-2 and Request-3 at the same time with 10000 users (which means 30000 concurrent requests) - put them under Parallel Controller

For conducting such load you at least will need to follow JMeter Best Practices and eventually perform operating system tuning
